# Type hinting with cyclic dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

I am building a Django/DRF application and have the following models:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    some_field = models.TextField()

    some_method(self, user):
        pass


class User(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The method `some_method` of the company model uses a user as input. The code itself works fine. However, how can I type hint this parameter to get IDE support / code completion in PyCharm? Declaring it like `some_method(user: User):` yields an "Unresolved reference" error which makes sense since the user class is declared further down in the file. Is there a workaround or do I have to live without code completion?

Comment: Code completion for *what*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem For the fields, methods etc. of the User model within Company.some_method.

Comment: Thanks for referring to the linked question. Both wrapping the type hint in quotes and adding `from __future__ import annotations` do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type in quotes, linters understand it but it does not cause runtime error.

Example:

```
some_method(user: "User"):
```